# Changing HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name after User is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently working on a ASP MVC application. And was wondering if there is a way of changing HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name once the user has logged in.

I want to be able to do this to allow the user to change his/her username, and so need HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to be changed once they have done that.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can not do this:)

It is filled during authentication. Simpliest solution is when user changes username - log him out, and ask for login.

**Update**

It will work only with custom provider. If you are using standard one, i believe it can't be changed at all.

As an alternative solution you can try to do next:
When user tries to change his name:
1. Create new user 
2. abandon session 
3. remove old user
4. change all data which related to user to a new account
5. log him in once again with new user.

Comment: Cool cheers, I've gone with simpler solution, by logging the user out and getting them to sign back it. Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a terrible, non-friendly solution

Comment: waaaayy late response, but you can in fact add an additional identity using `User.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity)`. Just make sure you account for multiple identities when referencing the current user.

Comment: You create a new principal and identity (with the new name) then replace the current user with the new principal.